# Logic behind counting the views of a page

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I m trying to created a code for the page in which no. of views are needed to be shown in the bottom of the page.

I don't know what will be the logic behind counting the views. let's say the views like on the home page of the stackoverflow. I like they way they display. And the logic for the same. (it'll be done via the php-mysql)

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, Dave. Are you looking for *all* views, or just *unique* views?

Answer (score 1):

Set a function to select if their IP address is already in the table where you track your hits, if it is don't add one to the count, otherwise add 1 to the count as well as their IP for future tracking.

Comment: thanks Dan,  Do you want to say that I have to increase the no. of count everytime the user visits, regardless of the ip ??

Answer (score 0):

You'd stick something like this in the header of each page:

```
<?php
    updatePageHitCount('name of page here');
?>
```

where the 'name of page here' is some unique identifier for the page. The function would then basically just do some SQL:

```
UPDATE pagehitcounts
SET hitcount = hitcount + 1
WHERE pageID = 'name of page here';
```

Of course, you'd want something a little more robust, but this would be the basics.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I would like to go ahead with more advanced, this code will not be useful if i visit the same every 5 minutes, and it'll show 60 views in 1 hour.

Comment: @dave: one view every 5 minutes != 60 views per hour. something wrong with the arithmetic there.

Comment: yes, it's now 12 times per 60 minutes. but that's code which i m looking into